# Electron.js app: Bootstrap dropdown menu won't open

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, electron, package.json

I'm trying to use Bootstrap in my first **Electron.js app**. The dropdown button does appear, but the menu itself doesn't appear when I click on the button. I suspect there is something wrong with how I've added Bootstrap and jQuery to the app.

Here is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Magic</title>
    <script>let $ = require('jquery');</script>
    <script>require('popper.js');</script>
    <script>require('bootstrap');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <img src="../assets/true.png">

    <h1>Magic Demo!</h1>
    <p>Welcome to the most magical demo ever!</p>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
              type="button"
              id="dropdownMenu2"
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I added **Bootstrap**, **jQuery** and **Popper.js** via **npm** and this is the relevant part of my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.3.2",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  },
```

Also, I discovered that on the Electron DevTools, I get the error:
`"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on Node.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the bootstrap.js before the content. If the elements do not exist in the DOM when the script is loaded it will have no effect.

The [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#js) tell you where to place the script:

> ... near the end of your pages, right before the closing `</body>` tag, to
> enable them.

Comment: Thanks, I put all the script tags at the bottom but that hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap 4.6.0 drop-down menu doesn't open with jQuery version 3.6.0, but works correctly with jQuery 3.5.1. I just tried it, and it's true.

Try downgrading jQuery to version 3.5.1.